# How to surround a column with double quotes in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I want to surround the selected column entries with double quotes whenever there is a special character say ' | ' in the column value .

```
select 
case
when (p.email_address_text like '%|%')
      then 'true' -- where i want to surround the entry with double quotes
      else p.email
end as email
from dev_databse..tmp_new_student p where p.email_address_text like '%abc@abc.com%';
```

In the above query in the true condition I want to surround email by double quotes whenever email contains | . For ex if email is  a|bc@gmail.com , I want it to be "a|bc@gmail.com". Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Netezza does have a concat operator . we can use. || to concat two string . Was able to achieve the desired out put with this